# Nested attributes reject_if model has more than four children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have the below scenario:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => ""

end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

How can I reject the creation if one question has more than 4 answers?

Comment: I believe `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => -> {|q| q['answers'].count > 4}` should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

I hope it work for you.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => -> {|q| q['answers'].count > 4}, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :question
end
```